# Forming a particular (averaged) block matrix with numpy

Tags: matrix, numpy

Say I have a set of $n \times n$ matrices $A_1, ..., A_m$ as numpy arrays. I'd like to create the block matrix defined below.

[image]

I'm looking for a clean, elegant, and easy-to-interpret way of doing this in numpy. I tried this with `np.block`:

```
a1, a2 = np.full((2, 2), 1), np.full((2, 2), 2)
out = np.block([[a1, (a1+a2)/2],
                [(a1+a2)/2, a2]])
```

but that approach doesn't generalize to an arbitrary number of $m$ matrices.

An approach that I found which **is** general is the following:

```
A = np.array([a1, a2])
out = (A[:, :, None, :] + A.transpose(1, 0, 2)[None, :, :, :]).reshape(n * m, -1)
```

but that one, while being efficient, is fairly hard-to-read (this code will be read much more often than written).

`scipy.linalg.block_diag` gets me halfway there, but I don't get the off-diagonals.

Can anyone think of a good alternative solution? I was thinking of looking into numpy's array-generation-from-function routines, but haven't found a good way of going about that yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
mats_row=np.array([[A1,A2,A3,...,A_n]]) #Create array of matrices with shape (1,M,N,N)
mats_column=np.transpose(mats_row,(1,0,2,3)) #Make a copy with shape (M,1,N,N)
block=.5*(mats_row+mats_column) #Add, broadcasting to a (M,M,N,N) array
```

This works by utilizing Numpy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) capabilities. The basic idea is similar to if you added a matrix where each row was $[A_1,A_2,..A_n]$ to a matrix where each column was $[A_1,A_2,..A_n]$, but broadcasting allows you to do this without ever explicitly forming these intermediates matrices.